# np.cast in numpy results in incorrect result

Tags: python, numpy

This use of np.cast:

```
np.cast['f'](np.pi)
```

results in an incorrect value for pi:

```
array(3.1415927410125732, dtype=float32)
```

why did this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real pi value up to a few digits more than `float32` precision (from [here](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~huberty/math5337/groupe/digits.html))

```
`3.14159265358979323846264338327950288...`
```

`float32` precision has an accuracy from 6 to 9 decimal places  (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format))

```
 3.1 4 1 5 9 2 7 4 1  0125732 #  your value
 3.1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3  5897    # actual value
 --1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   # (index of decimal place)
```

As you can see the deviation from the real value happens after the 7th decimal place. So that's the reason why it is not right after that

Comment: You can also check the resolution with `np.finfo('float32')`

Comment: If you want more precision try `np.cast['d'](np.pi)`, it'll cast to float64

Comment: ... or `np.cast['f8'](np.pi)` to get double precision (i.e. `np.float64`). `'f'` is equivalent to `'f4'`.